# replace string in xslt 2.0 with replace function

Tags: xslt

I have a string like this

```
"My string"
```

Now I want to replace `my` with `best` so that the output will be like `best string`.
I have tried some thing like this

```
 <xsl:value-of select="replace( 'my string',my,best)"/>
```

but probably its a wrong syntax

I have googled a lot but found nothing..every where the mechanism to do this XSLT 1.0 is explained.Can any one tell me how to do it in XSLT 2.0 ,The easy way compared to 1.0

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Given:

```
<xsl:variable name="s1" select="'My string'"/>
```

Simply use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace($s1, 'My', 'best')"/>
```

Note that a regular expression is applied. Meaning:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace('test.replace', '.', ':')"/>
```

Becomes:

```
::::::::::::
```

Be sure to escape the characters that have special meaning to the regular expression interpreter:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace('test.replace', '\.', '::')"/>
```

Becomes:

```
test::replace
```

Comment: @AKS: Are you sure you are using `XSLT 2.0`? If so maybe you should declare the namespace `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` in your XSLT and use the function as `fn:replace($s1, 'My', 'best')`. See: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: @AKS, you will need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or AltovaXML or XMLPrime if you want to use XSLT 2.0.

Answer (score 6):

First check, if your xslt processor (saxxon) is the latest release. Then you have to set 
`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"` in the head of your xslt-stylesheet. That's it.
Your code was fine, besides you forgot the apostrophs:

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace( 'my string',my,best)"/>
```

must be

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace('my string','my','best')"/>
```

Comment: How does one find out which xslt processor he is using?  I'm trying to use the `replace` function inside a  xsl form to be processed by Apache FOP 2.2 and changing the `xsl:stylesheet` version to 2.0 wasn't enough to solve my problem. Adding `xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"` didn't work either. Thanks!